# Overlapping divs with bootstrap navbar

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't want my divs to overlap and they are with the bootstrap navbar.
Could someone please help me with this as I'm not sure why its doing it? I've even tried to add some position: relative; and position: fixed;

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>MinecraftServerList | Minecraft Server List</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-default-green navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="http://www.minecraftserverlist.com"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.minecraftserverlist.com/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> Sponsors</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.minecraftserverlist.com"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i> Forums</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.minecraftserverlist.com"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i> Tools</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.minecraftserverlist.com"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i> Support</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="header-container">
            <div class="brand">
                <div class="container">
                    MinecraftServerList.com
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ad">
                <div class="container">
                    Your ad could be here!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
            <div class="container">
                © MinecraftServerList | Made by Joel Evans and Sebastian Semma | Minecraft is copyright Mojang and is not affiliated with this site.
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Heres my CSS

```
.navbar-default-green {
    background-color: #009933;
    border-color: #559a4b;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}
.header-container {
    margin: 0;
}
.brand {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    border-bottom-color: #DDD;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}
.ad {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-bottom-color: #DDD;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    line-height: 150px;
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use `padding-top` in body tag

```
<body style="padding-top:50px">
```

This is why beacuse the navbar is set to be fixed top, so it will stick at the top and overlaps the below divs

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/mYSGiLvTB4)

Hope this may useful for you